# Why PHP PDO bindValue not binding?

Tags: php, pdo, bindvalue

I have got a function for querying my database:

```
public function query($sql, $params = array()) {
    // reset error back to false
    $this->_error = false;

    // check query to prepare
    if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {
        $x = 1;
        if(count($params)) {
            foreach($params as $param) {
                $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                $x++;
            }
            print_r($this->_pdo->errorInfo());
        }
        // check query execution
        if ($this->_query->execute()) {
            $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
        } else {
            // error
            $this->_error = true;
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

But there is something not working. The line `$this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);` is not doing what it ought to do. There is no binding happening. The array with parameters thrown into the function seems fine. The `$sql` statement is fine as well and is returning:

```
INSERT INTO responders (`username`, `password`, `salt`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
```

That should be perfect for using the bind method. But after going through the foreach loop nothing has changed and the _query var is still the same. So no entry to the DB will be made at all. I also tree to use the errorInfo and got back:

```
Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => )
```

Can anyone give me a clue what I am missing here?

Comment: did you bother checking the return value of the bindValue() call?

Comment: @TheFrost: what good would that do? you'd be changing it to an equality test, and the prepared statement would be lost. e.g. you're advocating further breaking the script.

Comment: Interesting.. the return value of the bindValue()call is: 1

Comment: Querying of error info before running the query seems premature. What does that give _after_ the execute? And `debugDumpParams` might give more insight.

Comment: May I ask why I earned a down vote for my question?

Answer (score -2):

without reading all that messy code, here is how this function have to be

```
public function query($sql, $params = array()) {
    $query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute($params);
    return $query;
}
```

And don't forget to [set PDO in exceptions mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990857/reference-frequently-asked-questions-about-pdo#15990858)

Comment: Well... I am sure, I am not the greatest PHP-coder. But have at least a sense of politeness. There is nothing wrong to ask questions if you are the one who wants to advance...